# Not able to set return object inside Lambda function Java 8

Tags: java

Not able to set the return object inside the lambda function. I am getting error as "**Local variable readytoInsert defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final**" . Any other way please?

```
@PostMapping("/application/digital/v1/customers/{customerId}/neworder/")
 public MicroserviceResponse createOrder(@PathVariable("customerId") final 
   String customerId,@RequestBody final String requestBody, final MicroserviceResponse msResponse) throws MicroserviceException {

    JSONObject requestJSON;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    UserDTO readytoInsert = new UserDTO();
    try {
        requestJSON = new JSONObject(requestBody).getJSONObject("data");
        final String jsonData = requestJSON.toString();
        UserDTO orderSource = mapper.readValue(jsonData, UserDTO.class);
        orderSource.getOrderConfigs().forEach(item -> {
           readytoInsert = orderServiceValidator.validateOrderService(item, orderSource, orderSource.getOrderConfigs());
        });     
        **// I need to use the return object outside forEach loop, to perform other stuffs**
       } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
    return msResponse;
}
```

Method return the DTO here

```
public UserDTO validateOrderService(final UserDTO.OrderConfigs service,
        final UserDTO userDTO,
        final List<UserDTO .OrderConfigs> masterServiceList) {


   return userDTO;
 }
```

Comment: Why do you want to overwrite `readytoInsert` for each item. What is your intention?

Comment: In other words, you are calling `orderServiceValidator.validateOrderService` for each *item* and which returned `UserDTO` do you want? the last one?

Comment: What actually you are doing in validateOrderService. Do you want single valid dto

Comment: @user7. Yes i am iterating the list and preparing the object after successful validation in that validate method.Inside the loop i will make db call to insert and outside the method i will make rest API call by passing the return object to other system.

Comment: Is that method going to mutate the passed `UserDTO` and return the same? If yes, why do you want to return it?

Comment: that UserDTO is modified inside the validate method, hence I'm returning latest one..

Comment: @Gaurav. Each list is iterated and return with modified UserDTO.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean validateOrderService(final UserDTO.OrderConfigs service,
        final UserDTO userDTO,
        final List<UserDTO .OrderConfigs> masterServiceList) {

     //do validation
 }
```

Define convert method if you need.

```
 public UserDTO convert(UserDTO dto){
      //do conversation
      return dto
    }
```

Use Java Stream API

```
UserDTO userDto = orderSource.getOrderConfigs()
             .stream()
             .filter(item->validateOrderService(item, orderSource, orderSource.getOrderConfigs()))
             .map(this::convert)
             .findFirst();
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Can you please give some more detail what we are doing here in "filter" and "map"  and "findFirst" ? will it iterate orderSource.getOrderConfigs() ?

Comment: filter is for validating the each UserDTO and map is for converting dto. Yes it will iterate over each item and filter it and if match found it map method convert the dto and first converted dto will be returned

Comment: Not getting the use of convert method here?  i am calling validateOrderService from my controller?  Where i will get the modified UserDTO to covert method?

Comment: Method should do only one thing, as per its name validateOrderService it should do only validation of UserDto not the conversion. You should define a service method and from there should call the validateOrderService().

Comment: map(this::convert). though i define the covert method its not recognizing